# Minecraft: /setblock a playing jukebox

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I setblock a playing jokebox in Minecraft? I need the command.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? I just did a Google search and found the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Judge2020, that you should always try to find out your own question before coming here. Anyway, the command you want is:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:jukebox 0 replace {RecordItem:{id:"minecraft:record_wait",Count:1b}}
```

Remember, this will make the jukebox, and it WILL have the disc inside, but IT WILL NOT PLAY! That is simply how it works, and there is no way to make it play automatically (or so I am told).

Comment: _Might_ be able to have a hopper put the disc in, which would make it play - you'd just have to place an empty jukebox instead and have the hopper set previously (or bring both in). Would have to experiment to see if that would even work. I'm pretty sure the hopper would see the inventory.

Comment: The minecraft wiki says that you can't use hoppers on jukeboxes.